# Prove that the point-slope form of a linear equation does not depend on the point

Tags: analytic-geometry

I am stucked on the following challenge:
"If the line determined by two distinct points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is not vertical, and therefore has slope $(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$, show that the point-slope form of its equation
is the same regardless of which point is used as the given
point."
Okay, we can separate $(x_0, y_0)$ from the form to get:
$$y(x_2-x_1)-x(y_2-y_1) = y_0(x_2-x_1)-x_0(y_2-y_1)$$
But how exclude this point $(x_0,y_0)$ and leave only $x, y, x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2$ in the equation?
UPDATE: There is a solution for this challenge:
$$(y_1-y_2)x+(x_2-x_1)y=x_2y_1-x_1y_2$$
From the answer I found that
$$y_2(x-x_1)-y_1(x-x_2)=y(x_2-x_1)$$
... but why this is true?

Comment: I think they mean "whether you use $$(x_1,y_1)$ of $(x_2,y_2)$ as the given point."

Comment: Nope, because there is a solution for this challenge without x_0 and y_0. I updated the question.

Comment: If you are responding to my comment, that's what I meant, but I see that I messed up the MathJax.  I don't follow your update.  Why is *what* true?

Comment: You are right, thanks, finally I got it. The solution was so simple -_-. I posted the answer.
P.S. The last equation in the question was formed, by extracting the common part of the reworked point-slope equation and the answer. So it can be called cheating

Comment: No, it called learning, not cheating.  This is very common.  Once you solve a problem, and see what the answer is, you also see an easier way to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to saulspatz, the solution is to simply show, that whether we are using $(x_1, y_1)$ or $(x_2, y_2)$ as the given point, the equation does not change. So both equations:
$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$
$$y-y_2=m(x-x_2)$$
reduce to the
$$(y_1−y_2)x+(x_2−x_1)y=x_2y_1−x_1y_2$$